# Calculate steps/progress of combinatorial problem

Tags: combinatorics

Take five objects labeled 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5. Now try arranging them in all ways possible starting with

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

We will say that this is the first combination. Let's go a few steps forward

```
1 2 3 5 4
1 2 4 3 5
1 2 4 5 3
1 2 5 3 4
1 2 5 4 3
1 3 2 4 5
1 3 2 5 4
1 3 4 2 5
1 3 4 5 2
1 3 5 2 4
1 3 5 4 2
```

The last combination is

```
5 4 3 2 1
```

**Is there a way to know how many steps need to be taken until you reach (for example)**

```
3 5 2 1 4
```

**without trying it out?**
I have been trying to wrap my head around it but after spending too much time thinking about it, I wanted to ask if it is possible and if so, how to calculate the steps. If that is possible, an extension of this problem would be to add rotation to each object. The first combination followed by the next steps would be

```
1 2 3 4 5   everything 0°
1 2 3 4 5   everything 0° except 5 which is rotated by 90°
1 2 3 4 5   everything 0° except 5 which is rotated by 180°
1 2 3 4 5   everything 0° except 5 which is rotated by 270°
1 2 3 4 5   everything 0° except 4 which is rotated by 90°
1 2 3 4 5   everything 0° except 4 which is rotated by 90° and 5 by 90°
1 2 3 4 5   everything 0° except 4 which is rotated by 90° and 5 by 180°
```

Then last combination:

```
5 4 3 2 1   everything 270°
```

How many steps need to be taken to reach

```
3 5 2 1 4   3: 90°, 5: 180°, 2: 0°, 1: 270°, 4: 270°
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34230266/how-to-calculate-the-lexicographical-rank-of-a-given-permutation

Comment: @Yorch Thank you very much for that link. Unfortunately, I still have trouble applying the solution to my problem. It does make sense to me in the other question since there are only two classes, but I struggle understanding it for this one. I would be grateful, if you could elaborate your understanding of the solution to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start with finding the indexing problem for permutations alone. The method is this; for each number $x$ which whose position is $i$ spots from from the left, you add up $$(5-i)!\times(\text{the number of numbers which are to the right of and less than $x$}).$$ The result is a number between $0$ and $5!-1$, inclusive, so it uses the zero-indexed convention. If you want the index to be between $1$ and $5!$, you must add one.

That is, if your permutation is $[\pi_1,\pi_2,\pi_3,\pi_4\pi_5]$, the index is
$$
4!\cdot \text{number of $\{\pi_2,\pi_3,\pi_4,\pi_5\}$ below $\pi_1$}+\\
3!\cdot \text{number of $\{\pi_3,\pi_4,\pi_5\}$ below $\pi_2$}+\\
2!\cdot \text{number of $\{\pi_4,\pi_5\}$ below $\pi_3$}+\\
1!\cdot \text{number of $\{\pi_5\}$ below $\pi_4$},\\
$$
possibly plus one depending on convention.

For $[3,5,2,1,4]$, this works out to be
$$
4!\cdot 2+3!\cdot 3+2!\cdot 1+1!\cdot 0=68
$$

---

It is simple to modify this to account for the rotations as well.

First of all, if you were ranking sequences of rotations alone, it would be very simple. Simple read the sequence of rotations as an integer in base $4$, using the correspondence
$$
0^\circ = 0,\qquad 90^\circ = 1,\qquad 180^\circ = 2,\qquad 270^\circ = 3
$$
For example, the zero-indexed rank of $[90,0,270,180,270]$ is $$1\cdot 4^4+0\cdot 4^3+3\cdot 4^2+2\cdot 4^1+3\cdot 4^0.$$ Finally, you can combine these using
$$
\text{rank}=(\text{zero-indexed permutation rank})\cdot 4^5+(\text{zero-indexed rotation rank})
$$
Again, this rank will be zero-indexed.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. I get the first part and coincidentally thought about that solution tonight. I am sorry but the rotation formula part is still a bit cryptic to me. Does this reasoning make sense for 3 1 2 4 5 all 0°: For the first object (3), 1 and 2 must have been rotated 3 times each (+ initial state) at this position. Therefore the rank for 3 1 2 4 5 would be: 4*4*(4!) . Is that correct?

Comment: Here's how you find the rank of $(3:0^\circ),(1:0^\circ),(2:0^\circ),(4:0^\circ),(5:0^\circ)$. 
$$
\text{permutation rank}=2\cdot 4!+0\cdot 3!+0\cdot 2!+0\cdot 1!=2\cdot 4!\\ \text{rotation rank}=0\cdot 4^4+0\cdot 4^3+0\cdot 4^2+0\cdot 4^1+0\cdot 4^0=0\\ \text{rank $=$ (perm rank)$\times 4^5$+(rot rank)} = (2\cdot 4!)\times 4^5+0
$$(I deleted an old comment which had several mistakes). @resa

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but is the solution of (3 : 90°), (5 : 180°), (2 : 0°), (1 : 270°), (4 : 270°) = 70031? If that's the case, the formula is not entirely correct. Ignoring the current rotations of the objects (setting all to 0) I get 2*4!*4^5 + 3*3!*4^4 + 1*2!*4^3 + 0*1!*4^2 = 53888. Accounting for the current rotation status: 1*4!*4^4 + 2*3!*4^3 + 0*2!*4^2 + 3*1!*4 + 3*0!*4^0 = 6927. Adding those two up: 53888 + 6927 = 60815. I have tried to confirm it by writing a small js program which creates all solutions. https://replit.com/@resa25/Object-Rotation-Problem#script.js @MikeEarnest

Comment: @resa The correct computation is
$$
\text{perm rank}=2\cdot 4!+3\cdot 3!+1\cdot 2!+0\cdot 1!=68\\
\text{rot rank} = 1\cdot 4^4+2*4^3+0*4^2+3*4^1+3*4^0=399\\
\text{rank} = 68\times 4^5 + 399=\boxed{70031}
$$
You had (mistakes in red, should be deleted)
$$
\text{perm rank}=2*4!*\color{red}{4^5} + 3*3!*\color{red}{4^4} + 1*2!*\color{red}{4^3} + 0*1!*\color{red}{4^2}\\
\text{rot rank}=1*\color{red}{4!}*4^4 + 2*\color{red}{3!}*4^3 + 0*\color{red}{2!}*4^2 + 3*\color{red}{1!}*4 + 3*\color{red}{0!}*4^0\\
$$
Also, you did not multiply perm rank by $4^5$ before adding to rot rank.

Comment: That is exactly what I asked. That by using your formula I receive the rank 70031 which is not correct. The expected rank is 60815 (zero index based). The last possible rank is (5 4 3 2 1 all 270°) 5!*4^5 - 1 which is 122879. 5 4 3 1 2 (all 270°) is only 16 ranks less (if you try it by hand) = 122863, but your formula returns 121855 if I didn't make a mistake.

Comment: I apologize for misinterpreting your comment. Still, I assert that my formula is correct, so your method for generating solutions is mistaken. I wrote a python program which verifies my answer: https://replit.com/@mearnest/Permutations-and-rotations#main.py. I do not know javascript, so assuming your code is wrong, I am not able to assess the error.

Comment: Honestly, thank you for your effort! I think to have found the error, please take a look at my output again and add the indices 0 - 20 to your program. The 16th index in your program doesn't do what I need for my use case, since it didn't switch 5 and 4 to try it again, but incremented the rotation of 3. Your formula is correct for the permutation technique that your program generates and my approach fits the one my script generates. I should have added more steps to the rotation part of my question to prevent misunderstandings. I would upvote but I don't have enough points to do so.

Comment: @resa This will be my last comment. $\tag*{}$ OK, then I do not understand what order you are  generating the solutions in. If you were to **post a new MSE question,** where you **un-ambiguously** describe the order you want (not with just examples, but with mathematical expressions, clear English, or even pseudo-code), then I would happily answer that question.